# azure-function-express, @bittrance/azure-function-express does not support the latest node versions. Does anyone know any alternatives?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-functions, migration, middleware

I have used [azure-function-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-express#azure-function-express), ([@bittrance/azure-function-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bittrance/azure-function-express)) to connect Express application to an Azure Function handler, and make seamless usage of all middlewares that we are familiar with.

However, these two packages do not support the latest node versions. Does anybody have a solution?

```
const { createHandler } = require('@bittrance/azure-function-express');
const app = require('../intezUserServiceLib/index');
module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: could you please share the version you using v1 or v2?  please refer to this for using express in Azure [function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-function-express)

Comment: HI Sampath. This package is working fine for node versions upto 16. I need to upgrade it to 18. The code goes below.

Comment: const { createHandler } = require('@bittrance/azure-function-express');
 const app = require('../intezUserServiceLib/index');
 module.exports = createHandler(app);

Comment: please refer to this git Connect your Express application to an Azure Function [handler](https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express)

Comment: Post question details (including code) in the question - and **not** in a comment. You can [edit] your question. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask] in order to understand how this website works and how to correctly post a question.

Answer (score 1):

- The below code is an example of shifting from Express.js to Azure [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/shift-expressjs?tabs=javascript).

```java
// Express.js - server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send("Success!");
  } catch (error) {
    const err = JSON.stringify(error);
    res.status(500).send(`Request error. ${err}`);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Express.js app listening on port 3000');
});
```

```
// Azure Functions - hello/index.js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  try {
    context.res = { body: "Success!" };
  } catch (error) {
    const err = JSON.stringify(error);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: `Request error. ${err}`
    };
  }
};
```

```
| - hello
|   - function.json
|   - index.js
```

[image]

[image]

- The below code uses Azure Functions for Node.js and Express. The code's [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/shift-nodejs-express-apis-serverless/) is taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express).

```
const createHandler = require("azure-function-express").createHandler;
const express = require("express");

// Create express app as usual
const app = express();
app.get("/api/:foo/:bar", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    foo  : req.params.foo,
    bar  : req.params.bar
  });
});


module.exports = createHandler(app);
```

Refer to the DOC to use [Express](https://github.com/yvele/azure-function-express) as [middleware](https://securecloud.blog/2021/01/04/express-js-middlewares-on-azure-functions-via-custom-handlers/) and to [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)  [Express](https://expressjs.com/) application to an Azure Function [handler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node) using [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: Hi sampath its not working for node versions above 16.

Comment: Could tell what issue you are facing for the above  node version above 16